# ¿Como poner en negrita o subrayada la letra de un mensaje en Sweet Alert?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

Que tal quisiera saber ¿cómo puedo poner el `text` de mi mensaje en negrita o subrayada? Este es mi `JavaScript`:

```
else if (data.Existe == 2) {
    var text = $("#IdTemporada option:selected").text();
    swal("¿Está seguro de reemplazar el video de esta temporada: "+ text + "?", {
       buttons: {
          ok: "Si",
          cancel: "No"
      },
}
```

Comment: Swal ? es de **SweetAlert** ??

Comment: Francisco, si es de SweetAlert

Comment: Te función con alguna de las respuesta que te dieron ? no olvides marcarla como aceptada para que sea de ayuda a otros usuarios

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes manejarlo como html  y darle el diseño a tu mensaje

Ejemplo:

```
var text = "<b>Navidad</b>";
    swal({
      title: 'titulo',
      html: "¿Está seguro de reemplazar el video de esta temporada: "+ text + "?",

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Bueno es muy facil te dejo el enlace de la documentacion oficial de **`sweetalert2`**, hay encuentras varios ejemplos  https://sweetalert2.github.io/#examples.

Y te dejo un ejemplo funcional. revisa el **snippet**

```js
var text = "Navidad";

Swal.fire({
  title: '',
  type: 'info',
  html:
    '¿Está seguro de reemplazar el video de esta temporada: <br><b> '+text+'</b> ?'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8.18.0/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Swal.fire({
            icon: 'warning',
            title: 'Falta Información...',
            html: 'Seleccione una <b>Actividad</b> de la lista',
            //footer: '<a href>Why do I have this issue?</a>'
        });
```

solo cambia la etiqueta `text` a `html` y realiza los cambios que necesites.

Answer (score 2):

```
else if (data.Existe == 2) {
    var text = $("#IdTemporada option:selected").text();
    swal("¿Está seguro de reemplazar el video de esta temporada:<b> " + text + " </b>?", {
       buttons: {
          ok: "Si",
          cancel: "No"
      },
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Gracias por compartir tu conocimiento con la comunidad , tu pregunta quedaria mucho mejor si explicas que hace el codigo :)